# Solr 5.3.1 core missing when restart but still there

Tags: solr

Every time the server restarts the core is 'missing', but when I go to add it back I get an error about creating a core that already exists. The solr log file says:

"Could not create a new core in /opt/solr-5.3.1/server/webapps/[corename]/as another core is already defined there"

The core.properties file only has one line, it says name=[corename]. This is not a multi-core setup, it's just one core. However, every time the server restarts (including automatically or during a power outage) the core disappears and thus breaks the search on client-side because the core is no longer accessible for it. How can I get the core to persist on start-up? I read elsewhere I should check permissions, but what should I check exactly?

Using Solr 5.3.1 on CentOS 7.

EDIT: OK, so I noticed that the solr user owns all the folders EXCEPT for the webapps, which is owned by the root user. Could this be causing the issue?
EDIT: changed permissions and that does nothing. Core still always disappears on restart and needs to be manually added back via admin console, which throws error message as above.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Solr from default installation script you should look for core in /var/solr/ location and deleting the dir(If you have no data) manually followed by solr restart. hth.

Comment: thanks for the response. There's no dir under /var/solr, just a data folder with the solr.xml file. Currently the core I have is storing data under /opt/solr-5.3.1/server/webapps/[corename]/data. Does that seem right?

Comment: yes, for DATA directory its correct, for config Dir, you first need to search where solr is storing your config files. You can check it via core admin page in solr dashboard. Once you find the correct core config dir, rename it and restart solr. You will be able to create core via command. hth

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by " Once you find the correct core config dir, rename it and restart solr" ? My config for this core is at: /opt/solr-5.3.1/server/webapps/[corename] .  Do you mean delete it and restart or just rename?  It has all the files in it (including schema.xml, which I have modified obviously), so deleting seems dangerous. What does renaming do?

Comment: Also, I think it is important to note that when I tried to create a core from command line, it added it to var/solr/ location, and the core persisted after restart. However I have trouble linking this core to the webapp that uses it, so I need the core location to stay where it is for now under /opt/solr-5.3.1/server/webapps/[corename]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by 1) creating a new core at command line to be placed in the solr home (which was under var/solr), 2) copying over the conf files from the data directory in the old core, and 3) re-indexing.